# C#: video compression using aforge.net

Tags: c#, .net, compression, video-capture, aforge

My application receives a sequence of images (BitmapImage) from external device with rate 30 fps.
I'm using Aforge.net library for save the received stream in .avi file. 
I used the following code for inizializing the AVIWriter:

```
AVIWriter writer;
writer = new AVIWriter("wmv3");
writer.FrameRate = 30;
writer.Open("test.avi", 320, 240);
```

And for each frame received I add it in the video stream, with the following code line:

```
writer.AddFrame(ResizeBitmap(BitmapImage2Bitmap(e.ColorFrame.BitmapImage),320,240));
```

But the generated file is too heavy. (10 secondos corresponds to about 3Mb).

I tryied also setting a low level of `writer.Quality` , but the result seems the same (just 5-7% less).

So, I need a more efficient compression.

What are the compressions supported in Aforge.net ? What compression should I use in order to reducing the weight of saved file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that interframe compression is not used in AVIWriter (but I may be wrong).
You may try to use VideoFileWriter from Aforge.Video.FFMPEG instead:

```
var writer = new VideoFileWriter();
writer.Open("test.mpg", 320, 240, 30, VideoCodec.Default, 1000);
// add your frame
writer.WriteVideoFrame(frame);
```

Remember to put dlls from Externals/ffmpeg/bin from AForge zip into your output directory.

Comment: Don't forget though that using the FFmpeg can cause you to need to release your source under GPL if you use certain parts of the FFmpeg libraries.  There is version of AForge available that has just those available under LGPL (the lesser GPL not requiring you to distribute your personal sources)